# Social Authentication crashes after obfuscating with proguard

Tags: facebook, authentication, twitter, proguard, obfuscation

I have an application which uses social authentication (Twitter and Facebook). Before publishing it in app store I used proguard to obfuscate my code. All features work fine except authentication of Facebook and Twitter. As soon as I click on Login with facebook or login with twitter button the application crashes with message Unfortunately "APP Name" has stopped.
My twitter authentication class extends Activity and TwiterProfile.java class extends fragments.

here is my proguard configuration

```
-injars      bin/classes
-injars      libs
-outjars     bin/classes-processed.jar
-libraryjars libs\ksoap2-android-assembly-2.4-jar-with-dependencies.jar
-libraryjars libs\twitter4j-core-4.0.1.jar
-dontpreverify
-repackageclasses ''
-allowaccessmodification
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-dontwarn twitter4j.**
-dontwarn org.xmlpull.v1.**
-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
-keep public class * extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment
-keep public class * extends android.support.v4.app.ListFragment
-keep public class * extends android.app.Fragment
-keep public class * extends android.view.View {
    public <init>(android.content.Context);
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
    public void set*(...);
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}

-keepclassmembers class * extends android.content.Context {
   public void *(android.view.View);
   public void *(android.view.MenuItem);
}

-keepclassmembers class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
    static ** CREATOR;
}

-keepclassmembers class **.R$* {
    public static <fields>;
}

-keepclassmembers class * {
    @android.webkit.JavascriptInterface <methods>;
}
```

Here is twitterauthentication.java which is called from TwitterProfile.java class

```
public class TwitterAuthenticate extends Activity{
    private WebView webView;

    public static String EXTRA_URL = "extra_url";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_webview);

        setTitle("Twitter");

        final String url = this.getIntent().getStringExtra(EXTRA_URL);
        if (null == url) {
            Log.e("Twitter", "URL cannot be null");
            finish();
        }

        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
        webView.loadUrl(url);
    }


    class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

            if (url.contains(getResources().getString(R.string.twitter_callback))) {
                Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
                /* Sending results back */
                String verifier = uri.getQueryParameter(getString(R.string.twitter_oauth_verifier));
                Intent resultIntent = new Intent();
                resultIntent.putExtra(getString(R.string.twitter_oauth_verifier), verifier);
                setResult(RESULT_OK, resultIntent);
                /* closing webview */
                finish();
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you read: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started#proguard ? It say that you need some Facebook stuff.

Comment: That did the trick for facebook.Thank you. Checking dev.twitter for twitter solution.